# Magento 2 - How do you reorder front-end product page attributes?

Tags: magento2

I'm using the Luma theme.

On the product page, I'm trying to reorder the attributes **size** and **prints** (used to be called colors).

I want prints to be above size. I tried setting attribute sort position under storefront properties but nothing changed.

I tried reordering them in the attribute set and no luck there.

[image]